# Can ::cue selector not use 'transform' property?

Tags: css, html5-video

I am trying to 'mirror' the subtitles track in a video by using the transform property, but it seems that it is not working.

```
 ::cue{
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
```

Does anyone have idea how can I mirror them ?

Why am I doing this? Because I am showing the video mirrored, because it is user's webcam.

Comment: I don't believe `::cue` pseudo-class works with the `transform` property.

[10.3.2.3.1 The '::cue' pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/rendering.html#the-::cue-pseudo-element)

Comment: @Quantastical thanks for this, I was looking for this for so long..